# How to put Serial Number in dojox grid rows

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

How can we insert the row number as serial number in each dojo grid rows??
this must not change as grid is filtered or sorted.. any Idea??

Answer (score 1):

the solution i found is to use a 'get' in grid structure

add

```
function siFormatter(index){
return index + 1;
}
```

and add this to the structure of grid -

```
{field: "Si", name: "#", get : siFormatter, filterable: false}
```

disable sort for this column using canSort function in grid

donno if there is any other better solutions..